# Why instantiating my class doesn't work with getServletContext()?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, this

I would like to create a controller for my jsp page and I am wondering why should I use `this.getServletContext()` rather than creating an instance of my class. Let's say `HelloWorld world = new HelloWorld();`
then `world.getServletContext()` etc.

here's my code:

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     *
     * @param request
     * @param response
     * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
     throws ServletException, IOException {
        HelloWorld world = new HelloWorld();
        world.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

I get this:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering why should I use this.getServletContext() rather than creating an instance of my class lets say HelloWorld world = new HelloWorld(); then world.getServletContext() ...etc ?

The reason is that Servlets are not designed to work the way you mentioned. Here is the definition of a Servlet in [Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

> A servlet is a Java technology-based Web component, **managed by a container**, that generates dynamic content.

The term **managed by a container** means the servlet container is responsible to execute the lifecycle (creating, initializing, handling requests and destroying) of the servlet. But if you use **new** to create the servlet you are trying to work against the specification, and it will not work.

Read the section **2.3 Servlet Life Cycle** of the specification and it will answer your question thoroughly.

Comment: Oh I think now I understand, it's like I want to make the job that a container is supposed to do , which is creating the instance of the servlet :)

Thank you for your helpful comment! :)